# Como corrigir o erro no PHP - Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Curl error (code 77)

Tags: php

**Estou tentando parametrizar o Monolog no PHP e estou recebendo um erro.
Estou tentando interpretar este erro, porém não consigo entender o que esta 
ocorrendo, alguem sabe o que poderia ser ?.**

O erro

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Curl error (code 60): SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in
>   C:\wamp\www\alerts_monolog\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\Curl\Util.php:53
>   Stack trace: #0

Em outras perguntas disseram para colocar o arquivo "cacert.pem" na pasta do Wamp botei em C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.1\extras\ssl, o erro passou para este abaixo.

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Curl error (code 77): error 
>   setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: 
>   /path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem CApath: none in 
>   C:\wamp\www\alerts_monolog\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\Curl\Util.php:53
>   Stack trace: #0

O que eu posso fazer ?

**Não sei se é no código, mas o código é o seguinte**

```
<?php 

use Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SendGridHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\TelegramBotHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Logger;

require __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";

$logger = new Logger("web");
$logger->pushHandler(new BrowserConsoleHandler(Logger::DEBUG));
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__."/log.txt",Logger::WARNING));
$logger->pushHandler(new SendGridHandler("apikey","password","contato@jcacontadores.com.br","meu@email","nome_do_site_aqui: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s"),Logger::CRITICAL));

$logger->pushProcessor(function($record){
    $record["extra"]["HTTP_HOST"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    $record["extra"]["REQUEST_URI"] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $record["extra"]["REQUEST_METHOD"] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    $record["extra"]["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    return $record;

});

$tele_key = "TELEKEY";
$tele_channel = "@GRUPOKEY";
$tele_handler = new TelegramBotHandler($tele_key, $tele_channel,Logger::EMERGENCY);
$tele_handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter("%level_name%: %message%"));
$logger->pushHandler($tele_handler);

//DEBUG
$logger->debug("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);
$logger->info("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);
$logger->notice("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);

//FILE LOG
$logger->warning("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);
$logger->error("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);

//EMAIL
$logger->critical("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);
$logger->alert("Olá Mundo", ["logger" =>true]);

$logger->emergency("Essa mensagem foi enviada pelo Monolog!");
```

Comment: Edita o php.ini, lá vai encontrar o `curl.cainfo=`, aponta nele o local ... baixe o arquivo em http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: A resposta esta certa coloca como resposta e eu marco como correto. Mexi nestas opções
curl.cainfo="C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.1\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.1\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o curl deve editar o a linha do php.ini em:

```
curl.cainfo=
```

E para outros deve editar

```
openssl.cafile=
```

Você pode baixar o `cacert.pem`:

- http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

E depois ajusta assim:

```
curl.cainfo=unidade://local/aonde/baixou/o/certificado/cacert.pem
```