# Executar um PHP com parâmetros GET

Tags: php

Gostaria de executar um arquivo PHP com parâmetros GET.

Se uma ação é identificada, um arquivo php é acessado para capturar essa ação.

> teste.php

Dentro dele quero executar uma url PHP com parâmetros GET

Em teste.php temos:

```
(...)


if ($status == '3'){

//FAZER ALGO

    }

(...)
```

Se o status for 3 acessar:

> https://www.foo.com/teste2.php?nome=xxx&email=yyy

Eu já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
(...)

    if ($status == '3'){

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.foo.com/teste2.php?nome=$xxx&email=$yyy");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

      }

(...)
```

Mas a URL não é executada e não retorna nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer o mesmo?

Comment: Queira [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema, e uma explicação melhor do que seria o "não funciona". Uma lida no [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/70) pode ajudar muito no aproveitamento do site.

Comment: @Marcelo você está tentando redirecionar para a página desejada ou mostrar o conteúdo dela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar `$xxx = rawurlencode($xxx);` e `$yyy = rawurlencode($yyy);` antes do `curl_setopt`, porque se for caracteres como espaços ou outros pode complicar o envio do "path"

E também adicione o `http://` em:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.foo.com/teste2.php?nome=$xxx&email=$yyy");
```

> Nota: se for usar `https://` deve configurar o curl, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420944/3635

O código deve ficar assim:

```
$xxx = rawurlencode($xxx);
$yyy = rawurlencode($yyy);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.foo.com/teste2.php?nome=$xxx&email=$yyy");
```

---

Para "capturar" você deve usar `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` e para "evitar" possíveis redirecionamentos HTTP use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`, assim:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$xxx = rawurlencode($xxx);
$yyy = rawurlencode($yyy);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.foo.com/teste2.php?nome=$xxx&email=$yyy");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($resposta); //lê a resposta
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme! o erro era o tratamento no "nome" ($xxx)

Comment: @Marcelo por nada ;)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o comando "file_get_contents".
Acredito que é a forma mais simples de fazer uma chamada get em PHP.

Ficaria algo tipo assim

```
$retorno = file_get_contents(www.foo.com/teste2.php?nome=$xxx&email=$yyy);
```

Link da documentação do comando: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Leandro, não tinha pensado no file_get_contents. Utilizei a solução do Guilherme, de qualquer forma, obrigado!